# ¿Cómo puedo insertar datos de una tabla dinámica en mysql por medio de php?

Tags: php, html, tablas

Quisiera saber cómo puedo pasar mi tabla dinámica generada por medio de javascript con una función llamada guardar, a otro archivo llamado guardar.php y poder recorrer e insertar tantas veces como sea necesario en mysql.

Comment: Te agradeceriamos un ejemplo, gracias!